# UnityException: Transform child out of bounds (only in built APK)

Tags: unity, c#, transformation, gameobject

In the Unity Editor, this code helps me to get the Fog GameObject:

```
//get the fog GameObject
//0 :day , 1:night
if (tzPlayInfo.Instance.ENV_01_IDX == 0)
{
      if (FogEffect == null)
      {
             FogEffect = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(2).GetChild(0).GetChild(4).gameObject;
      }

} else
{
      if (FogEffect == null)
      {
             FogEffect = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(2).GetChild(1).GetChild(5).gameObject;
      }
}
```

And here's what in my hierarchy (for the night case):

[image]

[image]

As you can see on the photo it successfully gets the Fog GameObject. But when i build it and run the apk it gives me

> UnityException: Transform child out of bounds at MC_SettingBehaviour.Update () [0x00000] in :0

---

I tried what Arcane Engineer told me to do by using `Transform.Find()`

```
if (tzPlayInfo.Instance.ENV_01_IDX == 0)
{
      FogEffect = transform.Find("GO Root/day/01_Env_Lev01_test01/Fog01 (1)").gameObject;

} else{
      FogEffect = transform.Find("GO Root/night/01_Env_Lev01_night-test02/Fog01").gameObject;
}
```

But the problem when I build & run an APK, the error I get is replaced by:

> UnassignedReferenceException: The variable FogEffect of MC_SettingBehaviour has not been assigned

This is how i load my `fog env`

```
// 4. fog env.
        data.GetFogEnv(ref env03_idx, out prefabs);
        Load(ref prefabs, ref weather_env_root);
```

and I created a Load function here it is

```
void Load(ref GameObject[] prefabs, ref Transform root)
{
    if (prefabs != null)
    {
        GameObject obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < prefabs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (prefabs[i] == null) continue;
            obj = Instantiate(prefabs[i], root);
            obj.name = prefabs[i].name;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `GetFogEnv`

```
public void GetFogEnv(ref int env03_idx, out GameObject[] prefabs)
{
    prefabs = (env03_idx == 2 || env03_idx == 3) ? fog : null;
}
```

## EDITTED:

```
[SerializeField] GameObject[] cameraGameObject = new GameObject[46];

[SerializeField] GameObject FogEffect;

bool foundobjects = false;
void Update()
{
    if (tzPlayInfo.Instance.BLOCK_GAME_FLOW == false)
    {
        //if the option is livestreaming lets disable this script because it's useless.
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt(OptionPopup.LiveStreaming_) == 1)
        {
            this.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Find Objects
            if (!foundobjects)
            {
                StartCoroutine(FindObjects());
            } else
            {
                StopCoroutine(FindObjects());
            }
        }
        //if it is all found then execute this statement
        if (foundobjects)
        {
            //Save of Camera
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt(OptionPopup.CameraOptionSaving) == 1)
            {
                foreach (GameObject cameras in cameraGameObject)
                {
                    //lets check if theres a component
                    if (cameras.GetComponent<Bloom>() == null)
                    {

                    } else
                    {
                        cameras.GetComponent<Bloom>().enabled = true;
                    }

                    if (cameras.GetComponent<DepthOfField>() == null)
                    {

                    } else
                    {
                        cameras.GetComponent<DepthOfField>().enabled = true;
                    }

                    if (cameras.GetComponent<DepthOfFieldDeprecated>() == null)
                    {

                    } else
                    {
                        cameras.GetComponent<DepthOfFieldDeprecated>().enabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (GameObject cameras in cameraGameObject)
                {
                    //lets check if theres a component
                    if (cameras.GetComponent<Bloom>() == null)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cameras.GetComponent<Bloom>().enabled = false;
                    }

                    if (cameras.GetComponent<DepthOfField>() == null)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cameras.GetComponent<DepthOfField>().enabled = false;
                    }

                    if (cameras.GetComponent<DepthOfFieldDeprecated>() == null)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cameras.GetComponent<DepthOfFieldDeprecated>().enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            //Start of Fog
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt(OptionPopup.FogOptionSaving) == 1)
            {
                FogEffect.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                FogEffect.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator FindObjects()
{
    //AIR 
    cameraGameObject[0] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/AIR_1(Clone)/GameObject/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[1] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/AIR_2(Clone)/Camera").gameObject;

    //Paddock
    cameraGameObject[2] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Paddock_1(Clone)/CameraPos/GameObject/Camera").gameObject;

    //TV
    cameraGameObject[3] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/TV_1_far(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[4] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/TV_1_lead(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[5] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/TV_2_far(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[6] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/TV_2_lead(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;

    //LAST_SPURT && Test 30
    cameraGameObject[7] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/LAST_SPURT_1(Clone)/Pos/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[8] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test30(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;

    //Tests
    cameraGameObject[9] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test01(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[10] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test02(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[11] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test03(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[12] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test04(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[13] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test05(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[14] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test06(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[15] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test07(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[16] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test08(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[17] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test09(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[18] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test10(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[19] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test11(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[20] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test12(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[21] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test13(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[22] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test14(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[23] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test15(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[24] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test16(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[25] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test17(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[26] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test18(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[27] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test19(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[28] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test20(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[29] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test21(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[30] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test22(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[31] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test23(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[32] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test24(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[33] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test25(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[34] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test26(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[35] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test27(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[36] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test28(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[37] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test29(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[38] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/Test30(Clone)/Poss/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[39] = transform.Find("GO Root/Camera/HORSE_JOCKEY(Clone)").gameObject;

    //CommonEnv (follow_camera's_focus)
    cameraGameObject[40] = transform.Find("GO Root/CommonEnv/follow_camera's_focus/TOP_1(Clone)/Pos/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[41] = transform.Find("GO Root/CommonEnv/follow_camera's_focus/TOP_2(Clone)/Pos/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[42] = transform.Find("GO Root/CommonEnv/follow_camera's_focus/TOP_3(Clone)/Pos/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[43] = transform.Find("GO Root/CommonEnv/follow_camera's_focus/FRONT_1(Clone)/Pos/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[44] = transform.Find("GO Root/CommonEnv/follow_camera's_focus/SIDE_1(Clone)/Pos/Camera").gameObject;
    cameraGameObject[45] = transform.Find("GO Root/CommonEnv/follow_camera's_focus/SIDE_2(Clone)/Pos/Camera").gameObject;

    //get the fog GameObject
    //0 :day , 1:night
    if (tzPlayInfo.Instance.ENV_01_IDX == 0)
    {
        //Find GameObject Fog Effect
        FogEffect = transform.Find("GO Root/day/01_Env_Lev01_test01/Fog01 (1)").gameObject;
    }
    else
    {
        //Find GameObject Fog Effect
        FogEffect = transform.Find("GO Root/night/01_Env_Lev01_night-test02/Fog01").gameObject;
    }

    foreach (GameObject cams in cameraGameObject)
    {
        if (cams != null && FogEffect != null)
        {
            foundobjects = true;
            Debug.Log("All of the GameObjects have been found!!!!");
        }
    }
    yield break;
}
```

I build an apk using this code now it has this error

> 02-14 13:14:47.306 1828-1958/system_process W/InputDispatcher: channel '4ecb0710 com.x.x.x/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
>
> 02-14 13:14:47.306 1828-1958/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '4ecb0710 com.steet383.rh.google/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>
> 02-14 13:14:47.306 1828-1846/system_process W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '4ecb0710 com.x.x.x/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)'
>
> 02-14 13:14:47.306 1828-1846/system_process I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{4ecb0710 u0 com.x.x.x/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
>
> 02-14 13:14:47.306 1828-1846/system_process W/WindowManager: Force-removing child win Window{4ebbdfa0 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{4ecb0710 u0 com.x.x.x/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
>
> 02-14 13:14:47.306 1828-2020/system_process W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{4ea0bc74 u0 com.x.x.x.UnityPlayerActivity t8}: app died, no saved state

Comment: Hi NoobProgrammer. Firstly, I know you're trying to be respectful by using the word "sir," but Arcane Engineer has asked you to please not call them that. Just using a person's username is sufficient. Secondly, can you tell us where this fog object comes from? Does it get spawned dynamically at runtime or is it part of the scene in advance? Does it have any particular Components attached to it that we could look for?

Comment: @DMGregory it is spawned during run time . So what i did there is this `if (tzPlayInfo.Instance.BLOCK_GAME_FLOW == false)
        {` this line of code is the trigger the all my resources are loaded now and ready to play the game .

Comment: Can you show the script that spawns the fog? We might be able to use that to pass the fog reference to where it needs to be, if searching is proving difficult.

Comment: I editted my question @DMGregory

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Transform.Find(string name)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html) instead. Or keep public references that you can populate via inspector, e.g.

`public Transform myLightSource;`

You should never, EVER be using [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) in your code to retrieve various elements as that inevitably leads to the sort of problems you are having right now. Always use string names/IDs or symbolic references e.g. a constant like `MY_LIGHT_SOURCE` where that would be defined as `const int MY_LIGHT_SOURCE = 7;` or `#define MY_LIGHT_SOURCE 7`.

Moreover, in your specific case, `Transform` order is not guaranteed at runtime, so you are requesting an invalid index when running as APK. This will not happen if you `Find` by name.

Comment: How can i do it in `Transform.Find()` sir? Something like this : `FogEffect = Transform.Find("Go Root/night/01_Env_Lev01_night-test02/Fog01 (1)");`

Comment: @NoobProgrammer From the docs I linked:

`//Find the child named "ammo" of the gameobject "magazine" (magazine is a child of "gun").`
`ammo = gun.transform.Find("magazine/ammo");`

Comment: `FogEffect.transform.Find("Go Root/night/01_Env_Lev01_night-test02/Fog01 (1)");` so like that sir?

Comment: @NoobProgrammer I don't know your structure, and I don't care about the specific details. Figure it out yourself - try it, test it. You have the reference to the documentation. That's how the rest of us do it.

Comment: I've tested it and it gives me something like this `UnassignedReferenceException: The variable FogEffect of MC_SettingBehaviour has not been assigned.` This is how i do it `FogEffect.transform.Find("Screen3D/Go Root/night/01_Env_Lev01_night-test02/Fog01 (1)");`

Comment: That's a totally separate problem. If you don't know how to deal with an `UnassignedReferenceException`, you have bigger problems than this question you have asked. We expect you to know how to program when you ask questions here. Use google and _help yourself_ further.

Comment: I will occasionally use "magic numbers" for transform indices, but only when I'm dealing with exactly 1 (sometimes 2 children) and I know that that structure won't change (e.g. a scrolling list: I will always need to get from the `ScrollView` object to the `content` object and that layout is always identical: child-0, child-0).

Comment: @Draco18s That should only _ever_ be done in a dev environment. I mark any such lines of code as `//DEV` and clean them up ASAP. It's a "just for a few minutes while I'm figuring this out" thing. Even that case you mention might work just for you, but others will look at it and go "why?". Could cause other team members hesitation / pain later on.

Comment: @Draco18s Sir . What is really happening ? Because it works very smooth in editor but then when i build it the transform child out of bounds goes out.

Comment: @NoobProgrammer Did you read the whole answer? "Moreover, in your specific case, Transform order is not guaranteed at runtime, so you are requesting an invalid index when running as APK. This will not happen if you Find by name." And please stop calling me "sir".

Comment: @NoobProgrammer Here's a troubleshooting strategy you can use to find where your implementation is going wrong: try each level of the find individually. So `var root = transform.Find("GO Root"); if(root == null) { /* log your error & exit */ } var day = root.Find("day"); if(day == null) { /* log a different error & exit */ } ...` on and on down each level of the hierarchy. Then when you run, the error will tell you exactly where in the long hierarchy chain something undesired/unexpected happened, helping you focus your debugging efforts there.